# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, error-handling

I keep getting the "*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)*"

It says the error occurs at `p2, = plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')`, but I do not see a problem with that line. How do I fix it?

```
def g(x):
    return x * np.sin(1/x)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
y = g(x)
t = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
p = np.array([g(x) for i in range(len(t))])
xx = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
yy = g(xx)
plt.figure(1)
p1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label='Data points')
p2, = plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')
p3, = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'blue', label='Real')
plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2, p3], loc='best')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('g(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like you’re using python but your indentation got lost?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I did a copy paste from Python, but it went wrong. I have corrected it now

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: can you include the full traceback error?

Comment: The statement `p = np.array([g(x) for i in range(len(t))])` makes `len(t)` copies of `g(x)` and creates an 2-d array.  Is that really what you want `p` to be?

Comment: Can you try mine? I was able to plot it.

Comment: `p1, = ...` is an unpacking that throws this error if the RHS is a list or tuple without more than 1 element.  It isn't safe if you aren't absolutely sure of the nature/size of the RHS (here it's produced by the `plt.plot(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems, the error you're seeing is due to the fact that your `p` variable is inside a single element list, so you can just unpack that.

The second issue is that `t` and `p` are different lengths, I'm not sure how to fix that without knowing your goal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(x):
    return x * np.sin(1/x)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
y = g(x)
t = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
p = np.array([g(x) for i in range(len(t))])[0]
xx = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
yy = g(xx)
plt.figure(1)

print('t')
print(t)
print('p')
print(p)

p1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label='Data points')
p2, = plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')
p3, = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'blue', label='Real')
plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2, p3], loc='best')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('g(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')` consists of 30 `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects, but you're trying to assign it to a set with the length of 1.

If you need only first element from that `plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')`(and you do, if you need that only to show in the legend), simply get the first element.

```py
p2 = plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')[0]
```

Even better, do that for all 3 plots

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the difference between lists and np.array. Those behave very differently.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def g(x):
    return x * np.sin(1/x)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
y = g(x)
t = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
a = [i for i in range(len(t))]
a = np.array(a)
p = g(a)
xx = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
yy = g(xx)
plt.figure(1)
p1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label='Data points')
p2, = plt.plot(t, p, 'g--', label='Approx')
p3, = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'blue', label='Real')
plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2, p3], loc='best')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('g(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image Below]